# Environment.Stacktrace can be String.Empty?

Tags: .net

I'm curious when Environment.Stacktrace can return an Empty String. Using Reflector, I see it's calling new StackTrace(true), but I'm not familiar with a scenario when that returns no stack. Per the documentation for Environment.Stacktrace,

> A string containing stack trace information. This value can be String.Empty.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.stacktrace.aspx

Comment: have you referenced into all the run-times? WinPhone, PCL, WinRT etc?